# How do I scrape multiply country images from players on transfermarkt and still avoiding double citizenships?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new at scraping, and I've been helped with the most of my code, I'm not going for fancy or "writing the right way" now, just trying to get it working. It's for a project at my internship.

I'm trying to get information about the 500 most valuable players on [Transfermarkt](https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop). I've managed to scrape name, value, nationality, club, position, player image and club image. I also want to scrape the country images. I want to save the results in a CSV, which I've accomplished. But not with the country images. All of the other columns contains 500 rows, but the country images lists contains 1007. This is my error message:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/cljkn/Desktop/Python scraper github/.vscode/Scraping Transfermarkt.py", line 60, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Player":names,"Club":clubs, "Nationality":nats,"Position":position,"Value":values, "PlayerImgURL":playerURL,"ClubImgURL":clubURL,"CountryImgURL":natURL})
  File "C:\Users\cljkn\Desktop\Python scraper github\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 435, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\cljkn\Desktop\Python scraper github\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 254, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)       
  File "C:\Users\cljkn\Desktop\Python scraper github\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 64, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\Users\cljkn\Desktop\Python scraper github\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 365, in extract_index
    raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length")
ValueError: arrays must all be same length`
```

I've tried and tried with several different things. I've printed the list several times to see what the problem may be, and it seems like some players have two flags in their nationality, my guess is that they have double citizen ships. There is a break in the source code when this happens, and I've tried reading just the first value, but I can't get that to work. I've searched online for solutions but I can't find anything that suits my needs. I've tried a solution where I enter each players profile and then get the image from there, but I can't get that working. I've not found anything online that helps me with this. I've checked for duplicates in my list by removing those, this does not help me either.

Here is my code so far, and as I said, most is not done by me. The problem lies in #CountryImgURL:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}

pages = range(1, 21)

names = []
values = []
nats = []
clubs = []
position = []
playerURL = []
clubURL=[]
natURL=[]


for page in pages:

    r = requests.get(
        "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?page=%d" % page, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    pretty = soup.prettify()

    for table in soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'inline-table'}):
        content = table.contents
        names.append(content[0].text)  # Name
        position.append(content[1].text)  # Position

    for value in soup.findAll("td", class_="rechts hauptlink"): #Value
        values.append(value.get_text(strip=True))

    for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="zentriert"): #Nationality
        inner_grp = []
        for item in td.findAll("img", class_="flaggenrahmen", title=re.compile("^(?!http).*")):
            if item.get('title'):
                inner_grp.append(item.get('title'))
        if inner_grp:
            nats.append(inner_grp)

    for club in soup.findAll("img", src=re.compile("^http"), class_="", title=True)[:25]: #Club
        clubs.append(club.get("alt"))

    for img in soup.find_all('img', class_='bilderrahmen-fixed'): #PlayerImageURL
        playerURL.append(img.get('src'))

    for img in soup.find_all("img", class_="flaggenrahmen"): #CountryImageURL
        natURL.append(img.get('src'))

    for img in soup.findAll("img", src=re.compile("^http"), class_="", title=True)[:25]: #ClubImgURL
        clubURL.append(img.get('src'))


df = pd.DataFrame({"Player":names,"Club":clubs, "Nationality":nats,"Position":position,"Value":values, "PlayerImgURL":playerURL,"ClubImgURL":clubURL,"CountryImgURL":natURL})

df.head()

df.to_csv (r'S:\_ALL\Internal Projects\Introduction_2020\Transfermarkt\PlayerDetails.csv', index = False, header=True)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed there can be more than 1 country for the nationality. You are appending multiple times to the `natUrl` list here :

```
for img in soup.find_all("img", class_="flaggenrahmen"): #CountryImageURL
    natURL.append(img.get('src'))
```

So when you build the dataframe in the end, the lists don't have the same size which result in inconsistency eg player[x] will have nationality[x+1] because player[x-1] had 2 nationalities. In fact, you need to append exactly one item per iteration if you want all array to have the same size and in your code there are a lot of loop possibly appending multiple values per iteration (if there are multiple img tags)

I've made an example using only comprehension list :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

result = []

for page in range(1, 21):

    r = requests.get("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop",
        params= {"page": page},
        headers= {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"}
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    tr = soup.find_all("tbody")[1].find_all("tr", recursive=False)

    result.extend([
        { 
            "Player": t[1].find_all("td")[1].text,
            "Club": t[4].find("img")["alt"],
            "Nationality": t[3].find("img")["alt"], # for all nationality : [ i["alt"] for i in t[3].find_all("img")], 
            "Position": t[1].find_all("td")[2].text,
            "Value": t[5].text.strip(),
            "PlayerImgURL": t[1].find_all("img")[0]["src"],
            "ClubImgURL": t[4].find("img")["src"],
            "CountryImgURL": t[3].find("img")["src"] # for all country url: [ i["src"] for i in t[3].find_all("img")]
        }
        for t in (t.find_all(recursive=False) for t in tr)
    ])

df = pd.DataFrame(result)

df.to_csv('test.csv', index = False, header=True)
```